# Listing users with specific role (some of them do not appear on list)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want to list people who have certain roles like in the title, but some people who has this role do not appear on member list

Code:

```
const mRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === args.slice(0).join(" "));

message.channel.send(new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setAuthor("´" + `${mRole.name}` + "`", 'https://pngimg.com/uploads/moon/moon_PNG36.png', 'https://piv.pivpiv.dk/')
.setDescription(`${message.guild.roles.cache.get(mRole.id).members.map(m=>m.user).join("\n")}.`)
.setColor(mRole.color)
.setFooter(message.author.tag, message.author.displayAvatarURL()));
```

when it code works:

```
´+`
@Landon
@! miquQ.

Çağan#6467
```

Who have this role are much more than the code shows me.

Comment: I just copied your code and had no problems with it.

Comment: when it code works: [link](https://i.hizliresim.com/QiZwGT.png) those who have a role: [link](https://i.hizliresim.com/Zv1vmQ.png)

Comment: strangely it doesn't list some people

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Role#members`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/Role?scrollTo=members) only includes the *cached* members. So you will either have to cache all the users your Client has available, or fetch all the members on that guild.

- Cache all users

To cache all the users your Client has available, pass the `fetchAllMembers` option as `true` when instantiating the Discordjs Client (not very practical for bigger bots because of the large amount of users).

```js
const { Client } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ fetchAllMembers: true });
// ...
```

- Cache all guild members

To cache all the members for that specific guild, use `message.guild.members.fetch()`.

Note that the [`GuildMembersManager#fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch) method returns a promise, so you will probably want to use async/await or even `.then()`